# If I make a RESTful POST from a domain with an SSL Cert to another computer without a Cert, will the connection be secure?

Tags: javascript, rest, ssl, https

I want to send secure data from one computer to another. The source computer, with the data, has a domain name with an SSL Cert. The destination computer receiving the data is addressed by ip address and has no SSL Cert. This is a fully automated operation, no human or browser involved.

If I make a RESTful POST from the source computer's domain to the destination computer's ip address will the connection be secure, by virtue of it's SSL Cert?

I'm guessing not. But before I write complex code around this I'd like to get an authoritative answer.

If that IO is not secure the source computer could do a non-secure POST to trigger the destination computer, with the destination computer responding by doing an https GET to the secure source computer's domain to retrieve the data securely. But this will involve more complex coding "holding volatile data" between the trigger POST and secure GET that I'd much prefer to forego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to one simple issue:

**Does the target web server accept HTTPS connections?**

If it doesn't (which is likely if it "doesn't have an SSL certificate"), then you cannot open an HTTPS connection to it, have to use HTTP, and HTTP is not secure. It doesn't matter whether the requester has any SSL certificates stored; I have a ton of SSL certificates on my machine, that still doesn't make all of my HTTP requests secure.

> the source computer could do a non-secure POST to trigger the destination computer, with the destination computer responding by doing an https GET to the secure source computer's domain to retrieve the data securely

That is a decent workaround, and in fact preferable even if the target would have HTTPS. Barring other authentication schemes, anyone could make an HTTPS request at any time to the target machine sending it unauthenticated data. But if the target merely exposes a "web hook" which notifies it of events, and it has to get the data from an authenticated source itself, that subverts that issue.

Comment: That's the clarity I was seeking. Perfect.